# Getting ID instead of name in SharePoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list

I have a share point list in which exists a column - Modified by - which has values such as - LastName, FirstName 123.
When i associate workflow on this list to create the same fields in another list, i am not getting values like above mentioned instead i am getting network id such as flname123.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint treats fields that handle user info in a special way.  "Modified By" is one of those fields.  You'll want to check that the field you're copying the info into is of the type "person or group".  Then your workflow will bring it over in the expected way.